# I faced this first exception on row 1 with id

Tags: visualforce

//My apex code//

```
public class AccountWithCheckbox {
    Public List<wrapperclass> wraplist{set;get;}
    Public List<Account> acclist{set;get;}
    Public list<Account> accli{set;get;}
    Public AccountWithCheckbox(){
        wraplist=new List<wrapperclass>();
        acclist=new List<Account>();
        List<Account> acclist=[select id,name,phone,industry from Account ];
        for(Account a: acclist){
             wrapperclass wr=new wrapperclass(a,false);
            wraplist.add(wr);
        }



    }

    Public class wrapperclass{
        Public Account acc{set;get;}
        public boolean sel{set;get;}

        Public wrapperclass(Account a,boolean b){
            acc=a;
            sel=b;
        }

    }
    Public void selectedrecords(){

        for(wrapperclass wrap: wraplist){

            if(wrap.sel==true){
                // acclist.clear();
                acclist.add(wrap.acc);
            }
        }
        delete acclist;
        acclist.clear();
    }
}
```

my vf code//

```
<apex:page controller="AccountWithCheckbox" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Account details">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wraplist}" var="w">
              <apex:column headerValue="select" > 
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.sel}" >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!selectedrecords}" reRender="PB" />
                  </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!w.acc.id}" />
        <apex:column value="{!w.acc.name}" />
         <apex:column value="{!w.acc.phone}" />
            <apex:column value="{!w.acc.industry}" />
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="deleted Records" id="PB">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acclist}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.id}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.name}" />
            <apex:column value="{!a.phone}" />
            <apex:column  value="{!a.industry}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This was posted as another question so copying here:

> Delete failed. First exception on row 1 with id 0017F00000SWU3DQAX;
>   first error: ENTITY_IS_DELETED, entity is deleted: [] Error is in
>   expression '{!selectedrecords}' in page accountwithcheckboxvfpage:
>   Class.AccountWithCheckbox.selectedrecords: line 38, column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has
>   been notified.

Comment: Hi Raj can you provide the whole exception?

Answer (score 0):

I would put a `System.debug` where the Account wrappers are being added to the list in the constructor as well as the `selectedRecords`  methods to see which records you have in the list. From the error message it makes me think that you have a duplicate so it is trying to delete a record that is already deleted.